# FileNotFoundException in Netbeans on a Web Service running on Glass Fish server

Tags: java, web-services, serialization, netbeans, filenotfoundexception

This the event handler when the button is clicked on GUI. Implements the declared 
@WebMethod in class.

```
private void btn_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    int result;

    String username = us_textField.getText();
    String password = new String(pw_textField.getPassword());

    try {
        result = employeeLogin(username, password);
    } catch (IOException_Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        result = 0;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException_Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        result = 0;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException_Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        result = 0;
    }

    if (result == 0) {
        lbl_loginStatus.setText("Invalid Inputs");
    } else if (result == 1) {
        lbl_loginStatus.setText("Username and password does not match!");
    } else {
        lbl_loginStatus.setText("Login Successful!");
        new Choose().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }

}
```

This how the web service is declared in the same class.

```
private static int employeeLogin(java.lang.String username, java.lang.String password) throws IOException_Exception, FileNotFoundException_Exception, ClassNotFoundException_Exception {
    ws_employee.CWWsEmployee_Service service = new ws_employee.CWWsEmployee_Service();
    ws_employee.CWWsEmployee port = service.getCWWsEmployeePort();
    return port.employeeLogin(username, password);
}
```

This is the Web Service Code.

```
EmployeeMainController controller = new EmployeeMainController();
@WebMethod(operationName = "EmployeeLogin")
public int EmployeeLogin(@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    return controller.EmployeeLogin(username, password);
}
```

This is the `EmployeeLogin(username, password)` method declared in `EmployeeMainController.java` class. During this method a ArrayList initialized by `LoadData()` method.

```
public int EmployeeLogin(String username, String password) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    // Loading to the array list from the text file.
    ArrayList<EmployeeStruct> loadArray = new ArrayList<EmployeeStruct>();
    loadArray = LoadList();

    for (EmployeeStruct val : loadArray) {
        if (val.getEmpUsername().equals(username) && val.getEmpPassword().equals(password)) {
            return 2;
        } else if (val.getEmpUsername().equals(username) || val.getEmpPassword().equals(password)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `LoadData()` method is declared as below. This is simply a deserializing method. A have initialized the file path as this `public static String filename = "cw_employeeData.txt";`

```
public ArrayList<EmployeeStruct> LoadList() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<EmployeeStruct> employeeList = new ArrayList<EmployeeStruct>();
    File file = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    try {
        while (true) {
            EmployeeStruct x = (EmployeeStruct) ois.readObject();
            // System.out.println(x.toString());
            employeeList.add(x);

        }
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Completed reading from the file " + filename);
    }

   // employeeList.add(admin);
    return employeeList;
}
```

But when the code is executed, `ws_employee.FileNotFoundException_Exception: cw_employeeData.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)...` error comes in the console.

Even I have located the `cw_employeeData.txt` file in the root directory alongside the `Root/src` folder.